# Are there any third party tools for Kubernetes UI?

Tags: kubernetes

Are there any third party tools for Kubernetes UI? Such as to view pods on the main page or to edit the config of an object?

Answer (score 2):

Here we go the list of K8s dashboard alternatives

- **Lens - K8s** https://k8slens.dev/

The best K8s IDE for **monitoring**, **Debugging**

- **K8Dash**
  https://github.com/herbrandson/k8dash, web, node.js

“K8Dash is the easiest way to manage your Kubernetes cluster.”

- **Konstellate**
  https://github.com/containership/konstellate, web, Clojure

“Visualize Kubernetes Applications”

- **Kubernator**
  https://github.com/smpio/kubernator, web, node.js

“Kubernator is an alternative Kubernetes UI. In contrast to high-level Kubernetes Dashboard, it provides low-level control and clean view on all objects in a cluster with the ability to create new ones, edit and resolve conflicts. As an entirely client-side app (like kubectl), it doesn’t require any backend except Kubernetes API server itself, and also respects cluster’s access control.”

- **Kubernetes Dashboard**
  https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard, web

“Kubernetes Dashboard is a general purpose, web-based UI for Kubernetes clusters. It allows users to manage applications running in the cluster and troubleshoot them, as well as manage the cluster itself.”
Kubernetes Operational View
https://codeberg.org/hjacobs/kube-ops-view, web

“Read-only system dashboard for multiple K8s clusters”
Uses WebGL to render nodes and pods.

- **Kubernetes Resource Report**
  https://codeberg.org/hjacobs/kube-resource-report/, web

“Report Kubernetes cluster and pod resource requests vs usage and generate static HTML”
Generates static HTML files for cost reporting.

- **Kubevious**
  https://kubevious.io/, web

“Application-centric Kubernetes viewer and validator. Correlates labels, metadata, and state. Renders configuration in a way easy to understand and debug. TimeMachine enables travel back in time to identify why things broke. Extensible. Lets users define their own validation rules in the UI.”

- **Kubricks**

https://github.com/kubricksllc/Kubricks, desktop app

“Visualizer/troubleshooting tool for single Kubernetes clusters”

- **Octant**

https://github.com/vmware/octant, web, Go

“A web-based, highly extensible platform for developers to better understand the complexity of Kubernetes clusters.”
Weave Scope
https://github.com/weaveworks/scope, web

“Monitoring, visualisation & management for Docker & Kubernetes”

Refrence doc : [here](https://kube-web-view.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alternatives.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is the dashboard (https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) or the now deprecated kube-ui (https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-ui).

Also I've played with Weave Scope which has a pretty cool integration with k8s: https://www.weave.works/products/weave-scope/

Answer (score 1):

We are using  https://github.com/ElasticBox/elastickube to manage users and permissions to deploy services and pods.

Comment: The problem is it only shows pods and services from the namespaces default and kube-system.

Comment: I thought you could change the namespace in UI

Answer (score 1):

The [fabric8 console](http://fabric8.io) provides a console to manage resources as well as full continuous delivery pipelines built on top of Kubernetes. Some great articles & blog posts about it [here](https://blog.fabric8.io/).

Answer (score 1):

We are using kubernetic (www.kubernetic.com) in order to see/scale/delete kubernetes resources. It still has some issues with displaying correct information but in general it's nice.

Comment: please post only answers